# How to keep each new word in single quotation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I used to get 100's of tables which needs to keep in single quotations on daily basis. Rite now I am using Excel but it would be great if we can do it in SQL Server.

**Input**

```
schemaname.table1,schemaname.table2,schemname.table1s45k
```

**Output**

```
'schemaname.table1','schemaname.table2','schemname.table1s45k'
```

Thanks to everyone for your great effort.

Comment: More detail is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(MAX) = 'schemaname.table1,schemaname.table2,schemname.table1s45k'

SELECT @Input,
       ''''+REPLACE(@Input, ',', ''',''')+''''
```

Comment: great helped me lot.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL syntax:

```
Declare @String Varchar(8000) = 'schemaname.table1,schemaname.table2,schemname.table1s45k'

Set @String = '''' + Replace(@String, ',', ''',''') + ''''

Select @String
```

Comment: great helped me lot.